# About the usage of “on”

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Is the following title correct:

On Equations, Series and the General Method for Solving Questions

I.e. can I use “on” meaning about like this? Because the two first are in plural and unspecific, on the otherhand the last one is not; it is a specific thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no issue with the use of 'on' like this.

If you want to be more explicit, you could use 'regarding' instead.

Also, whilst some may disagree, I would encourage the use of a comma before the 'and' to disambiguate as to whether you are referring to two or three things:

"On Equations, Series, and the General Method for Solving Questions"

With the comma it is clear that 'Series' and 'the General Method for Solving Questions' are two different things.  Without the comma, they might be a single thing if someone was not familiar with the general subject matter.

It seems sensible to always be unambiguous if you can.

Alan.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. Last thing, if it were: “On Equations, Series and the General Method for Solving A” which A is something totally different from Equations and Series. Would we still need to use the comma? Just to be sure

Comment: I would always use a comma (plus 'and') before the last item in a list to completely disambiguate.  The comma is not absolutely necessary, and it is not wrong to omit it, but my general view is that we should never create doubt if we can avoid it.